# Importing a package in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

First off, apologies if my question is worded naively, as I am new to Python and Colab development. I have mounted my Drive onto my Colab notebook and inserted a path to a directory labeled "backend". It is structured as follows:

```
backend-> 
    solutions->
        __init__.py
        **(other files)
    **(other files)
```

I am trying to import my solutions directory as a package into my main.py script, which I have as a code block at the end of my notebook. I am attempting to "import solutions" into main.py, but it is telling me that "import solutions cannot be resolved" even though it recognizes its path. Does anyone have any ideas of what is happening here? The code and import works as expected on my local machine. I even attempted to make solutions into a package by including a README and a simple setup.py file, and while I was able to install it, it gave me a SystemExit error which I suspect originated from my setup.py.

---EDIT---
[new setup that copies the "solutions" directory to content. Still getting same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvLbL.png)

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried yet?

Have you tried the following?

```
# Mount your google drive in google colab
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

# Insert the directory
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')
```

**From here, be sure to have given access to your "My Drive" (security pop-up)**

Then check:

```
!ls gdrive/MyDrive
```

On the left panel you should see something like this now:

*"test-colab" is a folder I've created just to show you*

[image]

Then you copy/import the folder you want into your content:

*Adapt the code below with your own paths*

```
!cp -av '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/test-colab' '/content/'
```

Check:

[image]

Check `working directory` before trying to import a `.yp`:

[image]

Comment: yep! but it is still saying that "my_module" cannot be resolved as an import even though it recognizes its path. To clarify, "my_module" is a directory and not a .py file

Comment: wow thanks so much for such a thorough response! Unfortunately, even when I copy the directory into my content folder and then import it, I'm still getting the same error :"( I am attaching a screenshot to my original question to show how I set it up

Comment: @Ramya updated (bis) ;)

Comment: ah so I entered my working directory and tried importing the directory again, but it's still not resolving as an import. Could the issue be that I'm trying to import a folder as opposed to a .py file? I have an __init__ file in the directory I'm trying to import, which I thought made it a module.

Comment: Hum. 1. under "runtime" in colab, do the "disconnect and delete..." then try reimporting your folder like in my answer BUT before trying to import, do a "restart runtime" THEN do the "%cd" to the folder into "content" and NOW try to import your module. 2. Otherwise, "restart runtime" then try to do the "%cd" BUT with your "My Drive" path to your module this time. And try importing your module. If it doesn't work, I don't know. Importing your module into another IDE works?

Comment: still no luck :') it is importing in VSCode as expected, but hmm not sure why it isn't performing the same in colab. Will definitely let you know if I find a solution, thanks for your help again!